# "query end" step very long at random times

Tags: mysql, innodb

I'm benchmarking a web application, and I have a problem that occurs on about 1% of my queries, mostly UPDATES (but also sometimes INSERT). I did a profiling on those requests and it seems it's the query end step that takes a lot of time.

> ```
> starting  0.000029
> checking permissions  0.000005
> Opening tables    0.000017
> System lock   0.000005
> init  0.000032
> Updating  0.000052
> end   0.000030
> **query end   1.825892**
> closing tables    0.000025
> freeing items 0.000020
> logging slow query    0.000007
> logging slow query    0.000029
> cleaning up   0.000008
> ```

As I went through the documentation

> end : This occurs at the end but before the cleanup of ALTER TABLE, CREATE VIEW, DELETE, INSERT, SELECT, or UPDATE statements.
>
> query end : This state occurs after processing a query but before the freeing items state.

So does this mean the cleanup of my UPDATE is taking time ?
What does this step do exactly, how can I improve the performances ?

Thanks

Answer (score 12):

Issue solved by adding

```
innodb_flush_log_at_trx_commit = 0
```

in the /etc/my.cnf

There is an interlocking problem when multiple threads want to write the file at the same time, this way the log will be flushed every second.

Comment: Setting innodb_flush_log_at_trx_commit=0 isn't a solution to adopt lightly, it fundamentally changes the durability of your transactions!

Comment: Agreed. Setting innodb_flush_log_at_trx_commit naively can be dangerous, and the answer is misleading.

Comment: @PedroWerneck -- I tried the solution and it reduced my "query end" from 0.0006 to 0.00007. Any alternative solution?

Comment: Solution to what? query end 0.0006 doesn't seem to be a problem.