# mysql cursor taking long to execute

Tags: mysql, sql, stored-procedures, cursor

I have written a procedure which uses cursor to loop through the rows. It is taking too long to execute.

```
    CREATE PROCEDURE test_port()
    BEGIN
    declare done BOOL default FALSE;
    declare I,J,C,P,NOB int default 0;
    declare n,k,t int default 0;
    declare Lid int default 0;
    declare inTS timestamp;
    select max(id) into n from MAIN_TBL;
    select ctrValue into k from ID_CNT;
    set k=k+1;
    WHILE k<=n
    do
            select SourcePort,DestPort,LinkID,NoOfBytes,insertTime into I,J,Lid,NOB,inTS from MAIN_TBL where id=k;
            select count(*) into t from APP_PORTMAP_MSTR where Port in (I,J);
            IF(t=1) THEN
                    select Port into P from APP_PORTMAP_MSTR where Port in (I,J);
                    SET C=0;
                    select count(*) INTO C from LINK_APP_TBL where LinkID=Lid and Port=P;
                    insert into TRAFFIC_HIST_TBL(LinkID,Port,NoOfBytes,Time_1) values(Lid,P,NOB,inTS);
                    IF(C=0) THEN
                            insert into LINK_APP_TBL(Port,LinkID) values(P,Lid);
                    END IF;
            ELSE
                    if(I>J && J<>0) THEN
                            SET C=0;
                            select count(*) INTO C from LINK_APP_TBL where LinkID=Lid and Port=J;
                            IF(C=0) THEN
                                    insert into LINK_APP_TBL(Port,LinkID) values(J,Lid);
                                    insert into TRAFFIC_HIST_TBL(LinkID,Port,NoOfBytes,Time_1) values(Lid,J,NOB,inTS);
                            END IF;
                    ELSE
                            SET C=0;
                            select count(*) INTO C from LINK_APP_TBL where LinkID=Lid and Port=I;
      IF(C=0) THEN
                                    insert into LINK_APP_TBL(Port,LinkID) values(I,Lid);
                                    insert into TRAFFIC_HIST_TBL(LinkID,Port,NoOfBytes,Time_1) values(Lid,I,NOB,inTS);
                            END IF;
                    END IF;
            END IF;
    SET k=k+1;
    END WHILE;
    END$$
    \d ;
```

The possible reason for being slow is the "Insert" statements but can we improve the performance in any ways ? It is processing around 10K records at a time.

Comment: It basically checks it a Port is present in a master table, if so then makes an entry with the standard port. Else, the smaller port is considered to be a standard port and an entry is made.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Well, after carefully analysing the processlist, I found that "query end" state is taking very long time.

Hence, after searching some threads I found that setting innodb_flush_log_at_trx_commit to either 0 or 2 will speed up the operations but they prohibit innodb to be ACID complaint.

 Changing the values may result into 1 instruction loss in case of OS crash or power failure.

Ref:
[UPDATE statements are in "query end state"](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/15148176/update-statements-are-in-query-end-state)

Answer (score 0):

10k per second is a big number... you can try delete some indexes that you are not using or you can move your data files to faster disk (like SSD) that makes a huge difference...

Comment: I think you are right but as of now I dont have any such provision as we are in a POC Phase. The only way I can go through is some how try to make this efficient if possible. Also, I dont have much indexed on the tables... :(

Comment: so did you check your every select with explain ? a query without index can cause problem too, maybe your problem is your selects ?

also, myisam tables will lock table while writing, innodb locks only row, what is your table type ?

Comment: My Tables are innodb type

Comment: I don't know if this is possible for you but, maybe you can use memory tables for POC phase. I think SSD disk at production phase seems best solution for you, 10k per second is really to high for normal disks.