# Mysql commit sometimes takes minutes to finish

Tags: mysql, insert, transactions, commit, autocommit

Ive been having this problem for over 1 week now. Ive allready gone though the similar problems other people had here on stackoverflow. Im running Mysql 5.6.10.

1. ["query end" step very long at random times](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/6937443/query-end-step-very-long-at-random-times)
2. [UPDATE statements are in "query end state"](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/15148176/update-statements-are-in-query-end-state)
3. [Lots of "Query End" states in MySQL, all connections used in a matter of minutes](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/13234290/lots-of-query-end-states-in-mysql-all-connections-used-in-a-matter-of-minutes)

It happends randomly. But every 5 minutes or so, the commit takes a very very long time. And the size of the transation insert is usually around 1-2000 rows.

Ive been changing settings so much, ive kind of lost it i decided to create a questions here.

My inserts/updates are sqlfiles that have been generated by my program. Then i have a windows service that runs every 1,5 minutes processing the files. I build up a string of many sql files in a transaction mode. It works 4 out of 5 time very smooth, but 1 out of 5 it jams.

It usually happends on the same table, and most of the times its regarding inserts but also happends on updates. So i doubt it has to do with the structure of my tables but you never know until its solved :)

This is the table structure

```
CREATE TABLE `int_links_root_1` (
  `IntLinksRootId` bigint(20) NOT NULL AUTO_INCREMENT,
  `UrlId` int(11) NOT NULL,
  `Link` varchar(2000) NOT NULL,
  `AnchorText` varchar(500) DEFAULT NULL,
  `Title` varchar(2000) DEFAULT NULL,
  `PageText` varchar(8000) DEFAULT NULL,
  `Added` datetime DEFAULT NULL,
  `LastModifiedDatetime` datetime DEFAULT NULL,
  PRIMARY KEY (`IntLinksRootId`),
  KEY `Int_Links_UrlId_idx_1` (`UrlId`),
  FULLTEXT KEY `FullText` (`AnchorText`,`Title`,`PageText`),
  CONSTRAINT `Int_Links_UrlId_idx_1` FOREIGN KEY (`UrlId`) REFERENCES `urls` (`UrlId`) ON DELETE CASCADE ON UPDATE NO ACTION
) ENGINE=InnoDB AUTO_INCREMENT=1708708 DEFAULT CHARSET=utf8$$
```

These are 'show variables'

```
auto_increment_increment    1
auto_increment_offset   1
autocommit  ON
automatic_sp_privileges ON
back_log    90
basedir C:/Program Files/MySQL/MySQL Server 5.6/
big_tables  OFF
bind_address    *
binlog_cache_size   32768
binlog_checksum CRC32
binlog_direct_non_transactional_updates OFF
binlog_format   STATEMENT
binlog_max_flush_queue_time 0
binlog_order_commits    ON
binlog_row_image    FULL
binlog_rows_query_log_events    OFF
binlog_stmt_cache_size  32768
bulk_insert_buffer_size 8388608
character_set_client    utf8
character_set_connection    utf8
character_set_database  latin1
character_set_filesystem    binary
character_set_results   utf8
character_set_server    latin1
character_set_system    utf8
character_sets_dir  C:\Program Files\MySQL\MySQL Server 5.6\share\charsets\
collation_connection    utf8_general_ci
collation_database  latin1_swedish_ci
collation_server    latin1_swedish_ci
completion_type NO_CHAIN
concurrent_insert   AUTO
connect_timeout 10
core_file   OFF
datadir D:\MySQL6\
date_format %Y-%m-%d
datetime_format %Y-%m-%d %H:%i:%s
default_storage_engine  InnoDB
default_tmp_storage_engine  InnoDB
default_week_format 0
delay_key_write ON
delayed_insert_limit    100
delayed_insert_timeout  300
delayed_queue_size  1000
disconnect_on_expired_password  ON
div_precision_increment 4
end_markers_in_json OFF
enforce_gtid_consistency    OFF
eq_range_index_dive_limit   10
error_count 0
event_scheduler OFF
expire_logs_days    0
explicit_defaults_for_timestamp OFF
external_user   
flush   OFF
flush_time  0
foreign_key_checks  ON
ft_boolean_syntax   + -><()~*:""&|
ft_max_word_len 84
ft_min_word_len 3
ft_query_expansion_limit    20
ft_stopword_file    (built-in)
general_log ON
general_log_file    D:\MySQL6\WIN-0PCCFI7PPIN.log
group_concat_max_len    1024
gtid_executed   
gtid_mode   OFF
gtid_next   AUTOMATIC
gtid_owned  
gtid_purged 
have_compress   YES
have_crypt  NO
have_dynamic_loading    YES
have_geometry   YES
have_openssl    DISABLED
have_profiling  YES
have_query_cache    YES
have_rtree_keys YES
have_ssl    DISABLED
have_symlink    YES
host_cache_size 328
hostname    WIN-0PCCFI7PPIN
identity    0
ignore_builtin_innodb   OFF
ignore_db_dirs  
init_connect    
init_file   
init_slave  
innodb_adaptive_flushing    ON
innodb_adaptive_flushing_lwm    10
innodb_adaptive_hash_index  ON
innodb_adaptive_max_sleep_delay 150000
innodb_additional_mem_pool_size 8388608
innodb_api_bk_commit_interval   5
innodb_api_disable_rowlock  OFF
innodb_api_enable_binlog    OFF
innodb_api_enable_mdl   OFF
innodb_api_trx_level    0
innodb_autoextend_increment 64
innodb_autoinc_lock_mode    1
innodb_buffer_pool_dump_at_shutdown OFF
innodb_buffer_pool_dump_now OFF
innodb_buffer_pool_filename ib_buffer_pool
innodb_buffer_pool_instances    8
innodb_buffer_pool_load_abort   OFF
innodb_buffer_pool_load_at_startup  OFF
innodb_buffer_pool_load_now OFF
innodb_buffer_pool_size 524288000
innodb_change_buffer_max_size   25
innodb_change_buffering all
innodb_checksum_algorithm   innodb
innodb_checksums    ON
innodb_cmp_per_index_enabled    OFF
innodb_commit_concurrency   0
innodb_compression_failure_threshold_pct    5
innodb_compression_level    6
innodb_compression_pad_pct_max  50
innodb_concurrency_tickets  5000
innodb_data_file_path   ibdata1:10M:autoextend
innodb_data_home_dir    D:\MySQL6
innodb_disable_sort_file_cache  OFF
innodb_doublewrite  ON
innodb_fast_shutdown    1
innodb_file_format  Antelope
innodb_file_format_check    ON
innodb_file_format_max  Antelope
innodb_file_per_table   ON
innodb_flush_log_at_timeout 1
innodb_flush_log_at_trx_commit  0
innodb_flush_method 
innodb_flush_neighbors  1
innodb_flushing_avg_loops   30
innodb_force_load_corrupted OFF
innodb_force_recovery   0
innodb_ft_aux_table 
innodb_ft_cache_size    8000000
innodb_ft_enable_diag_print OFF
innodb_ft_enable_stopword   ON
innodb_ft_max_token_size    84
innodb_ft_min_token_size    3
innodb_ft_num_word_optimize 2000
innodb_ft_server_stopword_table 
innodb_ft_sort_pll_degree   2
innodb_ft_user_stopword_table   
innodb_io_capacity  200
innodb_io_capacity_max  2000
innodb_large_prefix OFF
innodb_lock_wait_timeout    30
innodb_locks_unsafe_for_binlog  OFF
innodb_log_buffer_size  2097152
innodb_log_file_size    262144000
innodb_log_files_in_group   2
innodb_log_group_home_dir   .\
innodb_lru_scan_depth   1024
innodb_max_dirty_pages_pct  0
innodb_max_dirty_pages_pct_lwm  0
innodb_max_purge_lag    0
innodb_max_purge_lag_delay  0
innodb_mirrored_log_groups  1
innodb_monitor_disable  
innodb_monitor_enable   
innodb_monitor_reset    
innodb_monitor_reset_all    
innodb_old_blocks_pct   37
innodb_old_blocks_time  1000
innodb_online_alter_log_max_size    134217728
innodb_open_files   2000
innodb_optimize_fulltext_only   OFF
innodb_page_size    16384
innodb_print_all_deadlocks  OFF
innodb_purge_batch_size 300
innodb_purge_threads    1
innodb_random_read_ahead    OFF
innodb_read_ahead_threshold 56
innodb_read_io_threads  4
innodb_read_only    OFF
innodb_replication_delay    0
innodb_rollback_on_timeout  OFF
innodb_rollback_segments    128
innodb_sort_buffer_size 1048576
innodb_spin_wait_delay  6
innodb_stats_auto_recalc    ON
innodb_stats_method nulls_equal
innodb_stats_on_metadata    OFF
innodb_stats_persistent ON
innodb_stats_persistent_sample_pages    20
innodb_stats_sample_pages   8
innodb_stats_transient_sample_pages 8
innodb_strict_mode  OFF
innodb_support_xa   OFF
innodb_sync_array_size  1
innodb_sync_spin_loops  30
innodb_table_locks  ON
innodb_thread_concurrency   10
innodb_thread_sleep_delay   0
innodb_undo_directory   .
innodb_undo_logs    128
innodb_undo_tablespaces 0
innodb_use_native_aio   ON
innodb_use_sys_malloc   ON
innodb_version  1.2.10
innodb_write_io_threads 20
insert_id   0
interactive_timeout 28800
join_buffer_size    262144
keep_files_on_create    OFF
key_buffer_size 67108864
key_cache_age_threshold 300
key_cache_block_size    1024
key_cache_division_limit    100
large_files_support ON
large_page_size 0
large_pages OFF
last_insert_id  0
lc_messages en_US
lc_messages_dir C:\Program Files\MySQL\MySQL Server 5.6\share\
lc_time_names   en_US
license GPL
local_infile    ON
lock_wait_timeout   31536000
log_bin OFF
log_bin_basename    
log_bin_index   
log_bin_trust_function_creators OFF
log_bin_use_v1_row_events   OFF
log_error   D:\MySQL6\error_log.txt
log_output  TABLE
log_queries_not_using_indexes   OFF
log_slave_updates   OFF
log_throttle_queries_not_using_indexes  0
log_warnings    1
long_query_time 3.000000
low_priority_updates    OFF
lower_case_file_system  ON
lower_case_table_names  1
master_info_repository  FILE
master_verify_checksum  OFF
max_allowed_packet  4194304
max_binlog_cache_size   18446744073709547520
max_binlog_size 1073741824
max_binlog_stmt_cache_size  18446744073709547520
max_connect_errors  100
max_connections 200
max_delayed_threads 20
max_error_count 64
max_heap_table_size 16777216
max_insert_delayed_threads  20
max_join_size   18446744073709551615
max_length_for_sort_data    1024
max_prepared_stmt_count 16382
max_relay_log_size  0
max_seeks_for_key   4294967295
max_sort_length 1024
max_sp_recursion_depth  0
max_tmp_tables  32
max_user_connections    0
max_write_lock_count    4294967295
metadata_locks_cache_size   1024
metadata_locks_hash_instances   8
min_examined_row_limit  0
multi_range_count   256
myisam_data_pointer_size    6
myisam_max_sort_file_size   107374182400
myisam_mmap_size    18446744073709551615
myisam_recover_options  OFF
myisam_repair_threads   1
myisam_sort_buffer_size 209715200
myisam_stats_method nulls_unequal
myisam_use_mmap OFF
named_pipe  ON
net_buffer_length   16384
net_read_timeout    30
net_retry_count 10
net_write_timeout   60
new OFF
old OFF
old_alter_table OFF
old_passwords   0
open_files_limit    7048
optimizer_prune_level   1
optimizer_search_depth  62
optimizer_switch    index_merge=on,index_merge_union=on,index_merge_sort_union=on,index_merge_intersection=on,engine_condition_pushdown=on,index_condition_pushdown=on,mrr=on,mrr_cost_based=on,block_nested_loop=on,batched_key_access=off,materialization=on,semijoin=on,loosesc...
optimizer_trace enabled=off,one_line=off
optimizer_trace_features    greedy_search=on,range_optimizer=on,dynamic_range=on,repeated_subselect=on
optimizer_trace_limit   1
optimizer_trace_max_mem_size    16384
optimizer_trace_offset  -1
performance_schema  ON
performance_schema_accounts_size    100
performance_schema_digests_size 5000
performance_schema_events_stages_history_long_size  1000
performance_schema_events_stages_history_size   10
performance_schema_events_statements_history_long_size  1000
performance_schema_events_statements_history_size   10
performance_schema_events_waits_history_long_size   1000
performance_schema_events_waits_history_size    10
performance_schema_hosts_size   100
performance_schema_max_cond_classes 80
performance_schema_max_cond_instances   1215
performance_schema_max_file_classes 50
performance_schema_max_file_handles 32768
performance_schema_max_file_instances   1750
performance_schema_max_mutex_classes    200
performance_schema_max_mutex_instances  4429
performance_schema_max_rwlock_classes   30
performance_schema_max_rwlock_instances 2286
performance_schema_max_socket_classes   10
performance_schema_max_socket_instances 300
performance_schema_max_stage_classes    150
performance_schema_max_statement_classes    167
performance_schema_max_table_handles    2858
performance_schema_max_table_instances  556
performance_schema_max_thread_classes   50
performance_schema_max_thread_instances 358
performance_schema_session_connect_attrs_size   512
performance_schema_setup_actors_size    100
performance_schema_setup_objects_size   100
performance_schema_users_size   100
port    3330
preload_buffer_size 32768
profiling   OFF
profiling_history_size  15
protocol_version    10
proxy_user  
pseudo_slave_mode   OFF
pseudo_thread_id    1520
query_alloc_block_size  8192
query_cache_limit   1048576
query_cache_min_res_unit    4096
query_cache_size    0
query_cache_type    OFF
query_cache_wlock_invalidate    OFF
query_prealloc_size 8192
rand_seed1  0
rand_seed2  0
range_alloc_block_size  4096
read_buffer_size    65536
read_only   OFF
read_rnd_buffer_size    262144
relay_log   
relay_log_basename  
relay_log_index 
relay_log_info_file relay-log.info
relay_log_info_repository   FILE
relay_log_purge ON
relay_log_recovery  OFF
relay_log_space_limit   0
report_host 
report_password 
report_user 
secure_auth ON
secure_file_priv    
server_id   0
server_id_bits  32
server_uuid 48f32a6c-9836-11e2-9e13-984be17fa006
shared_memory   OFF
shared_memory_base_name MYSQL
skip_external_locking   ON
skip_name_resolve   OFF
skip_networking OFF
skip_show_database  OFF
slave_allow_batching    OFF
slave_checkpoint_group  512
slave_checkpoint_period 300
slave_compressed_protocol   OFF
slave_exec_mode STRICT
slave_load_tmpdir   D:\MySQL6\Temp
slave_max_allowed_packet    1073741824
slave_net_timeout   3600
slave_parallel_workers  0
slave_pending_jobs_size_max 16777216
slave_rows_search_algorithms    TABLE_SCAN,INDEX_SCAN
slave_skip_errors   OFF
slave_sql_verify_checksum   ON
slave_transaction_retries   10
slave_type_conversions  
slow_launch_time    2
slow_query_log  ON
slow_query_log_file D:\MySQL6\WIN-0PCCFI7PPIN-slow.log
socket  mysqlpipe6
sort_buffer_size    524288
sql_auto_is_null    OFF
sql_big_selects ON
sql_buffer_result   OFF
sql_log_bin ON
sql_log_off OFF
sql_mode    STRICT_TRANS_TABLES,NO_AUTO_CREATE_USER,NO_ENGINE_SUBSTITUTION
sql_notes   ON
sql_quote_show_create   ON
sql_safe_updates    ON
sql_select_limit    18446744073709551615
sql_slave_skip_counter  0
sql_warnings    OFF
ssl_ca  
ssl_capath  
ssl_cert    
ssl_cipher  
ssl_crl 
ssl_crlpath 
ssl_key 
storage_engine  InnoDB
stored_program_cache    256
sync_binlog 0
sync_frm    ON
sync_master_info    10000
sync_relay_log  10000
sync_relay_log_info 10000
system_time_zone    W. Europe Daylight Time
table_definition_cache  1400
table_open_cache    2000
table_open_cache_instances  1
thread_cache_size   8
thread_concurrency  10
thread_handling one-thread-per-connection
thread_stack    262144
time_format %H:%i:%s
time_zone   SYSTEM
timed_mutexes   OFF
timestamp   1368530016.924189
tmp_table_size  211812352
tmpdir  D:/MySQL6/Temp
transaction_alloc_block_size    8192
transaction_allow_batching  OFF
transaction_prealloc_size   4096
tx_isolation    REPEATABLE-READ
tx_read_only    OFF
unique_checks   ON
updatable_views_with_limit  YES
version 5.6.10-log
version_comment MySQL Community Server (GPL)
version_compile_machine x86_64
version_compile_os  Win64
wait_timeout    28800
warning_count   0
```

This is show status

```
Aborted_clients 26
Aborted_connects    1
Binlog_cache_disk_use   0
Binlog_cache_use    0
Binlog_stmt_cache_disk_use  0
Binlog_stmt_cache_use   0
Bytes_received  1203
Bytes_sent  1936957
Com_admin_commands  17
Com_assign_to_keycache  0
Com_alter_db    0
Com_alter_db_upgrade    0
Com_alter_event 0
Com_alter_function  0
Com_alter_procedure 0
Com_alter_server    0
Com_alter_table 0
Com_alter_tablespace    0
Com_alter_user  0
Com_analyze 0
Com_begin   0
Com_binlog  0
Com_call_procedure  0
Com_change_db   1
Com_change_master   0
Com_check   0
Com_checksum    0
Com_commit  0
Com_create_db   0
Com_create_event    0
Com_create_function 0
Com_create_index    0
Com_create_procedure    0
Com_create_server   0
Com_create_table    0
Com_create_trigger  0
Com_create_udf  0
Com_create_user 0
Com_create_view 0
Com_dealloc_sql 0
Com_delete  0
Com_delete_multi    0
Com_do  0
Com_drop_db 0
Com_drop_event  0
Com_drop_function   0
Com_drop_index  0
Com_drop_procedure  0
Com_drop_server 0
Com_drop_table  0
Com_drop_trigger    0
Com_drop_user   0
Com_drop_view   0
Com_empty_query 0
Com_execute_sql 0
Com_flush   0
Com_get_diagnostics 0
Com_grant   0
Com_ha_close    0
Com_ha_open 0
Com_ha_read 0
Com_help    0
Com_insert  0
Com_insert_select   0
Com_install_plugin  0
Com_kill    0
Com_load    0
Com_lock_tables 0
Com_optimize    0
Com_preload_keys    0
Com_prepare_sql 0
Com_purge   0
Com_purge_before_date   0
Com_release_savepoint   0
Com_rename_table    0
Com_rename_user 0
Com_repair  0
Com_replace 0
Com_replace_select  0
Com_reset   0
Com_resignal    0
Com_revoke  0
Com_revoke_all  0
Com_rollback    0
Com_rollback_to_savepoint   0
Com_savepoint   0
Com_select  5
Com_set_option  6
Com_signal  0
Com_show_binlog_events  0
Com_show_binlogs    0
Com_show_charsets   0
Com_show_collations 0
Com_show_create_db  0
Com_show_create_event   0
Com_show_create_func    0
Com_show_create_proc    0
Com_show_create_table   0
Com_show_create_trigger 0
Com_show_databases  0
Com_show_engine_logs    0
Com_show_engine_mutex   0
Com_show_engine_status  0
Com_show_events 0
Com_show_errors 0
Com_show_fields 0
Com_show_function_code  0
Com_show_function_status    0
Com_show_grants 0
Com_show_keys   0
Com_show_master_status  0
Com_show_open_tables    0
Com_show_plugins    0
Com_show_privileges 0
Com_show_procedure_code 0
Com_show_procedure_status   0
Com_show_processlist    0
Com_show_profile    0
Com_show_profiles   0
Com_show_relaylog_events    0
Com_show_slave_hosts    0
Com_show_slave_status   0
Com_show_status 3
Com_show_storage_engines    0
Com_show_table_status   0
Com_show_tables 0
Com_show_triggers   0
Com_show_variables  9
Com_show_warnings   0
Com_slave_start 0
Com_slave_stop  0
Com_stmt_close  0
Com_stmt_execute    0
Com_stmt_fetch  0
Com_stmt_prepare    0
Com_stmt_reprepare  0
Com_stmt_reset  0
Com_stmt_send_long_data 0
Com_truncate    0
Com_uninstall_plugin    0
Com_unlock_tables   0
Com_update  0
Com_update_multi    0
Com_xa_commit   0
Com_xa_end  0
Com_xa_prepare  0
Com_xa_recover  0
Com_xa_rollback 0
Com_xa_start    0
Compression OFF
Connection_errors_accept    0
Connection_errors_internal  0
Connection_errors_max_connections   0
Connection_errors_peer_address  0
Connection_errors_select    0
Connection_errors_tcpwrap   0
Connections 152
Created_tmp_disk_tables 0
Created_tmp_files   5
Created_tmp_tables  9
Delayed_errors  0
Delayed_insert_threads  0
Delayed_writes  0
Flush_commands  1
Handler_commit  0
Handler_delete  0
Handler_discover    0
Handler_external_lock   8
Handler_mrr_init    0
Handler_prepare 0
Handler_read_first  0
Handler_read_key    0
Handler_read_last   0
Handler_read_next   0
Handler_read_prev   0
Handler_read_rnd    1122
Handler_read_rnd_next   2463
Handler_rollback    0
Handler_savepoint   0
Handler_savepoint_rollback  0
Handler_update  0
Handler_write   1333
Innodb_buffer_pool_dump_status  not started
Innodb_buffer_pool_load_status  not started
Innodb_buffer_pool_pages_data   259
Innodb_buffer_pool_bytes_data   4243456
Innodb_buffer_pool_pages_dirty  170
Innodb_buffer_pool_bytes_dirty  2785280
Innodb_buffer_pool_pages_flushed    122362
Innodb_buffer_pool_pages_free   380
Innodb_buffer_pool_pages_misc   1
Innodb_buffer_pool_pages_total  640
Innodb_buffer_pool_read_ahead_rnd   0
Innodb_buffer_pool_read_ahead   14036
Innodb_buffer_pool_read_ahead_evicted   370
Innodb_buffer_pool_read_requests    15129702
Innodb_buffer_pool_reads    196618
Innodb_buffer_pool_wait_free    152
Innodb_buffer_pool_write_requests   727352
Innodb_data_fsyncs  18008
Innodb_data_pending_fsyncs  1
Innodb_data_pending_reads   0
Innodb_data_pending_writes  0
Innodb_data_read    3462483968
Innodb_data_reads   211501
Innodb_data_writes  155812
Innodb_data_written 4099368960
Innodb_dblwr_pages_written  122602
Innodb_dblwr_writes 2140
Innodb_have_atomic_builtins ON
Innodb_log_waits    0
Innodb_log_write_requests   157303
Innodb_log_writes   29814
Innodb_os_log_fsyncs    4332
Innodb_os_log_pending_fsyncs    0
Innodb_os_log_pending_writes    1
Innodb_os_log_written   83195392
Innodb_page_size    16384
Innodb_pages_created    3118
Innodb_pages_read   211072
Innodb_pages_written    122514
Innodb_row_lock_current_waits   0
Innodb_row_lock_time    261518
Innodb_row_lock_time_avg    411
Innodb_row_lock_time_max    30420
Innodb_row_lock_waits   635
Innodb_rows_deleted 0
Innodb_rows_inserted    103754
Innodb_rows_read    3291528
Innodb_rows_updated 86170
Innodb_num_open_files   52
Innodb_truncated_status_writes  0
Innodb_available_undo_logs  128
Key_blocks_not_flushed  0
Key_blocks_unused   53581
Key_blocks_used 4
Key_read_requests   248
Key_reads   4
Key_write_requests  0
Key_writes  0
Last_query_cost 10.499000
Last_query_partial_plans    1
Max_used_connections    8
Not_flushed_delayed_rows    0
Open_files  22
Open_streams    0
Open_table_definitions  86
Open_tables 96
Opened_files    207
Opened_table_definitions    0
Opened_tables   0
Performance_schema_accounts_lost    0
Performance_schema_cond_classes_lost    0
Performance_schema_cond_instances_lost  0
Performance_schema_digest_lost  0
Performance_schema_file_classes_lost    0
Performance_schema_file_handles_lost    0
Performance_schema_file_instances_lost  0
Performance_schema_hosts_lost   0
Performance_schema_locker_lost  0
Performance_schema_mutex_classes_lost   0
Performance_schema_mutex_instances_lost 0
Performance_schema_rwlock_classes_lost  0
Performance_schema_rwlock_instances_lost    0
Performance_schema_session_connect_attrs_lost   0
Performance_schema_socket_classes_lost  0
Performance_schema_socket_instances_lost    0
Performance_schema_stage_classes_lost   0
Performance_schema_statement_classes_lost   0
Performance_schema_table_handles_lost   0
Performance_schema_table_instances_lost 0
Performance_schema_thread_classes_lost  0
Performance_schema_thread_instances_lost    0
Performance_schema_users_lost   0
Prepared_stmt_count 0
Qcache_free_blocks  1
Qcache_free_memory  10468392
Qcache_hits 0
Qcache_inserts  0
Qcache_lowmem_prunes    0
Qcache_not_cached   107
Qcache_queries_in_cache 0
Qcache_total_blocks 1
Queries 56190
Questions   25
Select_full_join    0
Select_full_range_join  0
Select_range    0
Select_range_check  0
Select_scan 10
Slave_heartbeat_period  
Slave_last_heartbeat    
Slave_open_temp_tables  0
Slave_received_heartbeats   
Slave_retried_transactions  
Slave_running   OFF
Slow_launch_threads 0
Slow_queries    2
Sort_merge_passes   0
Sort_range  0
Sort_rows   1122
Sort_scan   2
Ssl_accept_renegotiates 0
Ssl_accepts 0
Ssl_callback_cache_hits 0
Ssl_cipher  
Ssl_cipher_list 
Ssl_client_connects 0
Ssl_connect_renegotiates    0
Ssl_ctx_verify_depth    0
Ssl_ctx_verify_mode 0
Ssl_default_timeout 0
Ssl_finished_accepts    0
Ssl_finished_connects   0
Ssl_server_not_after    
Ssl_server_not_before   
Ssl_session_cache_hits  0
Ssl_session_cache_misses    0
Ssl_session_cache_mode  NONE
Ssl_session_cache_overflows 0
Ssl_session_cache_size  0
Ssl_session_cache_timeouts  0
Ssl_sessions_reused 0
Ssl_used_session_cache_entries  0
Ssl_verify_depth    0
Ssl_verify_mode 0
Ssl_version 
Table_locks_immediate   50440
Table_locks_waited  0
Table_open_cache_hits   4
Table_open_cache_misses 0
Table_open_cache_overflows  0
Tc_log_max_pages_used   0
Tc_log_page_size    0
Tc_log_page_waits   0
Threads_cached  3
Threads_connected   5
Threads_created 8
Threads_running 3
Uptime  3329
Uptime_since_flush_status   3329
```

I have tried all different innodb_flush_log_at_trx_commit settings. Im certain that my queries are optimal as they run very fast occasionaly, im almost certain that it has to do with my flushing. Ive also tried disabling autocommit but it still happends. Query cache is disabled. But any ideas are more than welcome. Maybe my disks are just to slow?

The system is not in production so i can restart it and test any suggestions.

Please let me know if i can provide any more details.

Answer (score 0):

Are you sure that previous commits already finished ? I am not faniliar with inner structure of mysql but couldnt it rebuild indexing, which is really slow for large tables. Or you can run multiple queries at a time but fifth one is just out of rhreads count and is in queue waiting for rest to finish.

Comment: I have automcommit set to 1. This means the commits are handled internally. I do pass very long massive inserts / update statement wrapped into one statement. I will try again without autocommit and try to manage the transactions myself. Maybe i missed something last time i tried. I also now created a new table without Primary key but unique key on urlid and link. problems still occur so its not the primary key creation which is slower in innodb.